# Richtextbox объединение двух rtf

Tags: c#, winforms, rtf

Задача в том, чтобы несколько разделов с текстом rtf хранить и затем, объединив их, выгрузить в файл.
Как это реализовать

Comment: `SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)` сохраняет форматирование. При чтении используйте `LoadFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)`

Comment: А вот если вы хотите два форматированных куска объединить просто конкатенацией строк - это в большинстве случаев работать не будет. Нужно использовать специальные библиотеки.

Comment: Использовал я эти методы, не срабатывало, все равно без форматирования. Сделайте милость, скажите какие библиотеки, заранее благодарен.

Comment: Покажите _код_, как и что вы делаете.

Comment: Все, решилось, косяк машины был, на другой все окей. Что там с библиотеками?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно использовать свойство Rtf для того, чтобы форматирование сохранялось:

```
string s = richTextBox.Rtf;
```

Если вы будете использовать `richTextBox.Text`, то форматирование не сохранится.